# Facebook API - Login error PHP SDK - A ?code parameter is added in the url and nothing happens

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, sdk

I use facebook login on my website with an API v2.4 application, PHP 5.4 installed on server but I have a big error on the authentication with facebook.

When I press the button "Login with facebook" instead of redirecting me and making the Session nothing happens and a `?code=XXXXXXXXXX` parameter is added to the URL.

I made a video to understand better: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Os6Zz-4hjQ

Here is my code for facebook:

```
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

 //1.Start Session
  session_start();
  require_once "config.php";
  $app_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  $app_secret = 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY';
  $redirect_url='http://myrealwebsiteurl.com/';

  FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);
  $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

  if(isset($session)){

    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
    $name = $graph->getProperty('id');
    $full = $graph->getProperty('name');    


    $full1=explode(' ', $full);
    $first=$full1[0];
    $rest=ltrim($full, $first.' ');


    $fname = $first;
    $lname = $rest;

    $_SESSION["fb"] = $name;
    $check = mysql_query(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($check);
$ip_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER)) {
    $ip_addr = array_pop(explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']));
}   
$geoplugin = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$ip_addr ) );
        if ( is_numeric($geoplugin['geoplugin_latitude']) && is_numeric($geoplugin['geoplugin_longitude']) ) {
            $lat2 = $geoplugin['geoplugin_latitude'];
            $lon2 = $geoplugin['geoplugin_longitude'];
}
                        mysql_query(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX);
                        mysql_query(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX);
                        mysql_query(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX);
    if ($row['yyy] != $_SESSION["fb"] || $row['ttt'] == '') {
    header("Location: fbregister.php");
mysql_query(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX);
mysql_query(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX);

    }
    else    {
        header("Location: profile.php");        

    }
  }
  else  {
       $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array(
       scope => 'email'
       ));
      echo '<a class="zocial facebook" id="zocial facebook" style="color: white; left: calc(10% - 10px); top: calc(48% - 5px); position: relative;" href='.$loginUrl.'>Login with facebook</a>';

  }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that mysql_query is deprecated, try turning on error reporting to see what's going on...

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /home/joshuat40/public_html/index.php on line 215

Notice: Use of undefined constant scope - assumed 'scope' in /home/joshuat40/public_html/index.php on line 270   -Theese are the errors that it shows me, it's about this line:   else  {
       $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array(
       scope => 'email'
       ));                               and this:  //1.Start Session
  session_start();